# mac look n feel on other platforms?

Tags: macos, cross-platform, look-and-feel

I'm just curious whether there is a gui framework that alloys you to use a mac look n feel on other platforms. presumably frameworks that use native APIs wouldn't be helpful (eg wxwidgets).
qt uses native API partially for mac look n feel, so that isn't useful.
what about swing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legally, you can't create the Mac look and feel on another platform. Apple owns the copyrights to it.

However, the [Quaqua Java Look-and-feel](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/) implements Java widgets that have that look-and-feel. If you have a good reason to use it in a non-commercial way, it may be a solution.

Comment: Directly from the linked page: "Due to copyright restrictions and technical constraints, Quaqua can be run on non-Mac OS X systems for development purposes only." How does this fit the bill for "other platforms" as specified by the OP?

Comment: @snicker: You can't get past that. Apple has copywritten the look. If you make a lookalike for a non-Apple platform, you can be sued. Period.

Comment: He asked for a widget framework with a Mac look-and-feel. I gave it to him. Not my fault it isn't legal to use in a commercial app.

Comment: +1 for legit and potentially critical answer.  If the look and feel is copyrighted, it's copyrighted.

Answer (score 8):

In general, don't do this.  Different platforms have different conventions, and your software should follow its platform's conventions to minimize the cognitive load of the user.

Unless, I guess, you're the only person who you ever expect to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Every operating system and desktop manager has a different way of implementing GUI elements. Trying to port an application that will look exactly the same as OSX onto these platforms will be difficult if you're looking to use the native controls. Secondly, like Gred stated, each one will have their own way of doing things and could cause user issues by having unusal icons, symbols and controls displayed or missing.

Though if you would like to attempt this, one of the multi-platform web browsers such as FireFox might be able to give you some idea of how to carry over the same general look and feel over the platforms.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last question, Swing does not ship with the Mac look and feel on platforms that aren't Mac-based.  This also applied to the other platform-specific look and feel elements.

While not the greatest solution, for Java, the [Nimbus L&F](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html) is a good alternative... but since it's now included in Java (as of 6u10), it's not available separately any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own style in Qt [and probably GTK*] to attempt to look the same (see [QStyle](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qstyle.html)).  However it probably isn't worth the time and effort and will piss off some users.  There are some windows themes that attempt to mimic the look.  I know the new version of parallels ships with something like that, but it looks rather funny as the margins, spacing, font, etc is completely wrong.